# Can I use BlackBerry Composer-to create graphics for my BlackBerry native application?

Tags: blackberry

I'm building an application that already has it's Iphone version. I must build the UI for BlackBerry on similar lines.

Chanced upon the BlackBerry Composer (Part of the Theme Builder) used to create graphics for the BlackBerry phone.

My questions are

1.My designer must use the BlackBerry Composer to build graphics i.e... Custom buttons, header and footer images, background image etc  and then import these into the Eclipse environment to integrate it with the functionality specific app code ? or is it that the Composer is to be used with the Theme Builder only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer is used to make Flash-style content for the BlackBerry. As far as I know, you don't have to use it to create your UI.